# Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected on return view?

Tags: php, laravel

This is really puzzling me.

Here is the code: 
https://gyazo.com/ba7d47653583d071d5fae6be20d8af25

When I have it as is with `return view('pages.ClientRedirect');` it throws the header error. If I take away the return and just have `view('pages.ClientRedirect');` the logic changes so it doesn't throw the error anymore, but obviously no longer works.

I've looked into the problem and the only answer I could find would be using `rawurlencode()` to encode the url, but then I get a missing view error because it's looking for an encoded url instead of the url my route is looking for `/ClientRedirect`

I must be overlooking something!

Comment: Are you returning the view as a string or you want to redirect to a given route?  If the latter, try `return redirect()->route('ClientRedirect');`

Comment: @AustinJenkins gives me a route not defined error. Which makes sense. What would be the route setup for this?

Comment: Do php artisan route:list to find out the names of your routes, or look in your routes.php file.  @AustinJenkins is correct in that you should be using return redirect instead of return view.  You can also use the syntax return redirect(route('RouteName')); or just return redirect('URL');

Comment: I knew of `return redirect ()` but it produces the same header error

Comment: The first route redirect (https://gyazo.com/3c63f69844364bd6da528b09be0fd038) doesn't work for some reason. It gives this error (https://gyazo.com/04b2774a17c2c704a99aa5e68cdf8a89) but when I run route:list I get this (https://gyazo.com/9de77df3280f9527670c65481caddb07). With this being the routing (https://gyazo.com/e7e3bf5a5f8eb5bc371a61d54ce06cc3). What's the issue here?

Comment: You're using the URL of the route in the route() helper, not the name of the route.  Try this: route('example'). Note from the output of your route:list command, *example* is the name of the route and *ClientRedirect* is the URL.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be that Laravel's built in auth wants to direct to a specific view and I was trying to redirect to a different view, ending up in two views being called at the same time hence the error.

I fixed it by overriding the OG with what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding the earlier comments that you should be returning a redirect not returning a view, the most common cause of the "new line detected on return view" error is an incorrectly terminated PHP file in one of your libraries or classes.  It's common convention these days to leave PHP files unterminated, e.g.

```
<?php
  some_code();
```

If however one of your library files that you are including includes a termination followed by a newline then that's the cause of your error.  Something like this:

```
<?php
  some_code();
?>
(blank line here)
```

... that would be the cause of your problem, because the blank line is emitted by the PHP interpreter as HTML at the point where the file is included. Remove the termination and the blank line and that should solve the problem.

Comment: I don't think any of my php files are terminated. Plus it only throws that error when I run a `return view` but otherwise works. Really lost on thi sone

Comment: Maybe it's the view that's problematic?  Try putting in a different route to a controller function somewhere and in that controller function do this: echo '[[['; echo view('pages.ClientRedirect'); echo ']]]'; and look *really* closely at the output.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ran into the same Issue when I wanted to migrate my WordPress website to a new host and I battle it throughout the night. The solution that worked for me is as given below..... ..

Actually, the error was caused by a space (white space) after the site or home URL in the WordPress database:
**The error message** (Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected.)

To fix this error, you can make changes to the site or home URL from within the WordPress Dashboard or through the WordPress installation's database.
Fix URLs within the WordPress Dashboard

***To fix the home and site URLs from within the WordPress Dashboard:***

- List item

  - Log into your WordPress Dashboard.
  - In the left-hand menu, go to Settings > General.
  - In the WordPress address (URL) and Site address (URL) fields, make sure there are no spaces after the URLs .
  - Click Save Changes.

***Fixing the URLs within phpMyAdmin (Manually Edit Database)***

To manually edit the site and home URLs within your WordPress database:

- List item

  - Log into cPanel.
  - In the Databases section, click on the phpMyAdmin icon.
  - From the left menu, select the database for your WordPress installation.
  - From the left menu, select wp_options.
    Find and edit the records for siteurl and home, ensuring that there are no spaces after the domain name.